# How can I find the region and carrier for an HTC phone?

Tags: htc, carriers, imei, localization

I'm using HTC One X.

To find RUU at htcdev.com, I need to know the region and carrier. Can I determine this using the IMEI or something else?

Comment: Kindly comment your network operator name.

Comment: @Psb phone operator is unlocked. But this option is not available in Operator list of htcdev.com